# How to include common files outside the template path in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

So I have a template builder that builds the template based on what folder value I pass in. I want to be able to extract a lot of the common templates into a third folder called "common" but I can't seem to figure out a way to copy this extra folder without Jinja assuming it's a whole other template set. Help please!

Folder structure

```
templates/
    /project1
    /project2
    /common
```

Current template function

```
def generate_templated_file(source, destination, variables, doc_type):
    """
    Read template file and write it

    Parameters
    ----------
    source : str
        Template file to read
    destination : str
        Location to store the rendered template
    variables : dict
        The variables required to render a particular file
    doc_type : str
        Type of file being generated (either Project1 or Project2)
    """
    environ = Environment(loader=PackageLoader("docs", "template"))
    if any(x in source for x in USER_FILES):
        with open(source, "r") as f:
            t = Template(f.read())
    else:
        t = environ.get_template(doc_type + "/" + source.split("/")[-1])
    with open(destination, "w") as f:
        f.write(t.render(variables))
```

Things I've tried/researched

- Jinja2.Markup seems to have similar functionality, but it doesn't parse any of the varibles and the templates in common will have variable.

Edit: I am not using Flask